# systemd init script for resque worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, systemd

i habe an nginx webserver running on an Ubuntu 16.04 Server.
Now i am trying to build an init script for resque worker and scheduler for a Rails app.

I created a file resque-worker.service in "/etc/systemd/system/" and it looks like this:

```
[Unit]
 Description=resque-worker for pageflow

[Service]
 Type=forking
 ExecStart=/home/pageflow/pageflow_daad/rake resque:scheduler QUEUE=* RAILS_ENV=production > /home/pageflow/pageflow_daad/log/resqueschedule.log &

[Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

For some reason after executing "systemctl daemon-reload" and "systemctl start name.service" i get this error:

```
$ systemctl status resque-worker.service
● resque-worker.service - resque-worker for pageflow
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/resque-worker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-05-17 15:52:38 CEST; 15s ago
  Process: 28096 ExecStart=/home/pageflow/pageflow_daad/rake resque:scheduler QUEUE=* RAILS_ENV=production > /home/pageflow/pageflow_daad/log/resqueschedule.log & (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

May 17 15:52:38 ostheim systemd[1]: Starting resque-worker for pageflow...
May 17 15:52:38 ostheim systemd[1]: resque-worker.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=203
May 17 15:52:38 ostheim systemd[1]: Failed to start resque-worker for pageflow.
May 17 15:52:38 ostheim systemd[1]: resque-worker.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 17 15:52:38 ostheim systemd[1]: resque-worker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

In this case i used the root path of my Rails app for "/home/pageflow/pageflow_daad/rake".

The times before where i tried the path of the rake binary i got the error:`May 17 15:30:26 ostheim rake[26846]: rake aborted!
May 17 15:30:26 ostheim rake[26846]: ArgumentError: couldn't find HOME environment -- expanding`~'`

I hope someone with more experience in this can help me out.

Thanks in advance and best regards,
Ronald

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After studying the several docu sites and the documentation itself i found a way to get this running. Just wanted to post this if someone finds this to be helpfull:

```
[Unit]
Description=resque-scheduler for pageflow

[Service]
User=yourUser
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/rails/app
ExecStart=/path/to/executeable/rake resque:scheduler &
Environment=QUEUE=*
Environment=RAILS_ENV=production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

With this script, a

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

&

```
systemctl start example.service
```

The Service startet running and runs like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I think there 2 types of errors inside the systemd unit. Here are some advices :

1) Let systemd capture your application logs, then use journalctl to look at it

```
journalctl -u resque-worker.service
```

2) Use env the systemd way :

```
[Unit]
Description=resque-worker for pageflow

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/home/pageflow/pageflow_daad/rake resque:scheduler
Environement=QUEUE=*
Enrironement=RAILS_ENV=production

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then,

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart resque-worker.service
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the advice.
I changed the systemd unit the way you told me, but still the same error occurs. journalctl -u resque-worker.service just giving me the code=exited status=203 thats all.
Any more ideas? thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not a rake expert but I think you need `Type=simple` not `Type=forking`, here is a a pointer to the documentation https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html